# Versioning files in Windows 10 Personal Laptop

Tags: windows-10, version-control

Often when I am working on a Word Report or a R script etc. I find myself naming a series of files as `"foo_file_4_July_3pm_"`  or `"foo_file_4_July_5pm_"` etc. just to allow me the ability to roll back in case I make a mistake that messes up things badly.

THis becomes messy pretty soon and clutters my directory with all kinds of files that I really need just for a backup. I remember when I was using Linux I had set up a neat system where periodically I could just commit a file and thus have a versioned set of files every time I made some major changes. I had set up a similar system on Windows a decade ago using Bazaar but that project seems now moribund.

Anyway to do this on Windows? Any recommendations for software that would do this?

PS. I am not looking for a software project sort of collaborative workflow with projects, merges etc. That's overkill. Just a quick and low-overhead way to version certain files in my laptop's ecosystem. e.g. I know Git, Subversion etc. but their workflow needs one to think in terms of projects and check out files. That's not what I want to do.

I just want to be able to seamlessly right click on files and say "save a version" to have the ability to roll back etc. Basically the whole Filesystem is a project.

Comment: But Git and SVN work almost exactly like Bazaar, from what I remember. In what way did you use it?

Comment: @user1686 Oh! Maybe I was doing something wrong. The way I used it was I had installed the GUI and for all files on right click I had a menu which used to allow me to commit a new version of any file or roll it back or see which versions I had. As I recall it all the files under say MyDocuments were maintained as part of one grand repository. There was a bazaar GUI for windows that did this all I recall.

Comment: Git is pretty lightweight and you're not forced to use Merges, features branches and more complicated workflow than just "commit (+push)". You can also benefit from a centralized repository (cloud) like bitbucket or github for public or private projects. We have plenty of project that does not need to be released (e.g. scripting) and we only have a master branch to keep all our commits.

Comment: You can also have a look to [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/), but cloud support is less easy, my recommendation would be to use git. Even you do not think you need complicated workflow, when you try local branches for different experimentations you will really like it (you can mess up your script in a branch without need to merge it to e.g. develop/master branch. You can also benefits from the tagging of specific versions.

Answer (score -3):

What you want is called the version control system. Try Git and SVN.

You can't find anything smaller than them!

Comment: In my opinion SVN is quite dead since git (mercurial) is in the market. SVN was very good in the beginning (as a replacement of CVS) but GIT is far more easy. I would not recommend tools that are less and less used (svn, cvs, sccs, rcs) or proprietary like Rational ClearCase (a nightmare...) or the Microsoft ones.